# 2.7.14 Abbott Abel's Convergence Test proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Abel's test: $\sum x_n $ converges and $(y_n)$ is a monotonically decreasing positive sequence. Then $\sum x_ny_n $ converges.

$\sum x_n $ is bounded by some $B$ (as it converges) and $y_n$ converges to something $\ge 0$. Using Summation by parts (2.7.12) we can show $|\sum_{j=m+1} ^n x_j y_j| \le 2 B y_{1} $.

Now we know that  $\sum x_n$  converges so we can apply Cauchy to find $|\sum_{j=m+1}^{n} x_j| < \frac{\epsilon}{2y_1} $. The leap is to assume  $B\le |\sum_{j=m+1}^{n} x_j| < \frac{\epsilon}{2y_1}$.

$\sum x_n $ is bounded by  $B$ i.e. $\sum x_n \le B$. How do you go from here to $B\le |\sum_{j=m+1}^{n} x_j|$?

Hints would be helpful.

Comment: I think you can find a stronger bound for your partial summation result. Can you show how did you do the partial summation? That's the key.

Comment: This feels like an imperfectly copied explanation from a book. For instance, you say the leap is to assume $B$... What leap? Who assumes that? Do you assume that? What is the actual question? If you are hoping that someone will have a copy of Abbott next to them, then you are severely restricting the audience of people who might answer your question, and you should instead edit your question to be self-contained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your observations are correct and will be of use, but your estimate from partial summation is not helpful in proving convergence. You are on the right track trying to establish the Cauchy criterion, that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a positive integer $N$ such that for all $n> m> N$ we have

$$\left|\sum_{j=m+1}^n x_j y_j \right| < \epsilon.$$

Summing by parts with $S_n = \sum_{j=1}^n x_j$,we get

$$\tag{1}\sum_{j=m+1}^n x_j y_j = y_{n+1} S_n - y_{m+1} S_m + \sum_{j=m+1}^n S_j(y_j - y_{j+1}).$$

By hypothesis the series $\sum_j x_j$ converges to some number $S$ and there must be a bound $B> 0$ such that $\left| S_n \right| \leqslant B$ for all $n$.  Also we have that the sequence $(y_j)$ is positive and monotonically decreasing.  Hence, we have $y_j \leqslant y_1$ for all $j$ and convergence $y_j \to y \geqslant 0$ as $j \to \infty$ as you observed.

From (1) we get

$$\sum_{j=m+1}^n x_j y_j = S_n(y_{n+1} - y_{m+1}) - y_{m+1} (S_m - S_n) + \sum_{j=m+1}^n S_j(y_j - y_{j+1}),$$

Using the triangle inequality,

$$\tag{2}\begin{align} \left|\sum_{j=m+1}^n x_j y_j\right| &\leqslant  |S_n|\, |y_{n+1} - y_{m+1}| + y_{m+1} \, |S_m - S_n| + \sum_{j=m+1}^n |S_j| \, (y_j - y_{j+1})\\ &\leqslant B\, |y_{n+1} - y_{m+1}| + y_1 \, |S_m - S_n| + B\sum_{j=m+1}^n (y_j - y_{j+1}) \\ &=   B\, |y_{n+1} - y_{m+1}| + y_1 \, |S_m - S_n| + B(y_{m+1} - y_{n+1}) \\ &= y_1 \, |S_m - S_n| + 2B | y_{m+1} - y_{n+1}|\end{align}.$$

You should be able to finish now by using the fact that the sequences $(y_j)$ and $(S_n)$ are convergent, hence Cauchy, and show that there exists $N$ such that the right-hand side of (2) can be made smaller than $\epsilon$ for all $n > m > N.$

Comment: So the last term on RHS($|y_{m+1} -y_{n+1}| $ is less than the cauchy criterion for $y_n$.  With the two cauchy criteria, we are done.

Comment: Yes. For example since $y_n$ converges there is $N_1$ where $|y_{m+1} - y_{n+1}| < \epsilon/(2B) \implies 2B|y_{m+1} - y_{n+1}|  < \epsilon/2$ for all $n > m > N_1$ by Cauchy criterion.